# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) on windows os XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am new to mysql, and I have installed XAMPP on my PC. I have tried all the ways suggested here in order to solve this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

after typing `mysql -u root`, I even changed my password to a new one, but it didn't help. What could I do to make my mysql working?

Comment: Try mysql -u root -p and enter the password. After you will ask for it.

Comment: The Windows password is totally independent from the mysql authentication, changeing your login password doesn't help anything.